# Creating new model with Django forms

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique = True)

class Review(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    burger = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(default = datetime.now)
    bun = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=RATINGS)
```

And a Form:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    place = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Place.objects.all())
    burger = forms.CharField(max_length = 128, help_text="Please enter the name of a burger."))
    comments = forms.TextField()
```

At this point users can choose the place they are reviewing a burger from. But what if they want to submit a review of a place that doesn't exist in my Place model? Is it possible to create a new Place from the ReviewForm if the Place doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible from your current ReviewForm, as your ModelChoiceField will only be populated with extant Place objects. You would probably want a separate form for registering a new burger place.

Comment: Is there any Django trick to allow someone to make a new Place object from this form? Or would I need to add a link to an PlaceForm form to allow users to create a new place somewhere else?

Comment: How are you creating Place objects to begin with? Create a form with all pertinent information that a user can fill out, and then use the entered data to create a new object.